# Strange error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location must not be null or empty Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello to all the exception that is coming out is something strange and I do not know why it gives me the truth andtes worked very well the fragment of the "post" where they could upload images without any problem now gives me that type of error and I do not know How to solve it since I'm still new to this

the exception:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.android.octa.memetixs, PID: 15679
                                                                       Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location must not be null or empty
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReference(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.android.octa.memetixs.ui.fragment.PostFragment$2.populateViewHolder(PostFragment.java:102)
                                                                           at com.android.octa.memetixs.ui.fragment.PostFragment$2.populateViewHolder(PostFragment.java:84)
                                                                           at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:196)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16639)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
                                                                        at android.widget.Line
```

the fragment of the error:

```
public class PostFragment extends Fragment {

private View mRootView;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder> mPostAdapter;
private RecyclerView mPostRecyclerView;
private User mmUser;
private Post mmPost;


public PostFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fabM);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PostCreateDialog dialog = new PostCreateDialog();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
        }
    });

     init();
    return mRootView;
}

private void init() {
    mPostRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_post);
    mPostRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    setupAdapter();
    mPostRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);
}

private void setupAdapter() {

    mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.row_post,
            PostHolder.class,
            FirebaseUtils.getPostRef()
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostHolder viewHolder, final Post model, int position) {
            mmUser = new User();
            mmPost = new Post();
            viewHolder.setNumComments(String.valueOf(model.getNumComments()));
            viewHolder.setNumLikes(String.valueOf(model.getNumLikes()));
            viewHolder.setTime(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(model.getTimeCreated()));
            viewHolder.setUsername(mmUser.getUser());
            viewHolder.setPostText(model.getPostText());







            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                    .getReference(mmPost.getPostImageUrl());
            Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(storageReference)
                    .into(viewHolder.postDisplayImageView);

            viewHolder.postLikeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onLikeClick(model.getPostId());
                }
            });

            viewHolder.postCommentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CommentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_POST, model);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


        }
    };

}

private void onLikeClick(final String postId) {
    FirebaseUtils.getPostLikedRef(postId)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        //user liked
                        FirebaseUtils.getPostRef()
                                .child(postId)
                                .child("numLikes")
                                .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                        long num = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
                                        mutableData.setValue(num - 1);
                                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        FirebaseUtils.getPostLikedRef(postId)
                                                .setValue(null);
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        FirebaseUtils.getPostRef()
                                .child(postId)
                                .child("numLikes")
                                .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                        long num = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
                                        mutableData.setValue(num + 1);
                                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        FirebaseUtils.getPostLikedRef(postId)
                                                .setValue(true);
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}


public static class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView postOwnerUsernameTextView;
    TextView postTimeCreatedTextView;

    ImageView postDisplayImageView;
    TextView postTextTextView;

    LinearLayout postLikeLayout;
    TextView postNumLikesTextView;

    LinearLayout postCommentLayout;
    TextView postNumCommentsTextView;


    public  PostHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        postOwnerUsernameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_post_username);
        postTimeCreatedTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        postDisplayImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_post_display);
        postLikeLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_layout);
        postCommentLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_layout);
        postNumLikesTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes);
        postNumCommentsTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_comments);
        postTextTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_post_text);
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        postOwnerUsernameTextView.setText(username);
    }

    public void setTime(CharSequence time) {
        postTimeCreatedTextView.setText(time);
    }

    public void setNumLikes(String numLikes) {
        postNumLikesTextView.setText(numLikes);
    }

    public void setNumComments(String numComments) {
        postNumCommentsTextView.setText(numComments);
    }

    public void setPostText(String text) {
        postTextTextView.setText(text);
    }

}
 }
```

the utils of firebase reference:

```
      public class FirebaseUtils {

//==============================================================================================
// USER REFERENCE
public static DatabaseReference getUserRef(String email) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.USERS_KEYS)
            .child(email);
}
public static FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
}






              // POST REFERENCE
public static DatabaseReference getPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.POSTS_KEY);
}
public static Query getPostQuery() {
    return getPostRef().orderByChild(Constants.TIME_CREATED_KEY);
}
public static DatabaseReference getMyPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.MY_POSTS)
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}





// POST LIKED REFERENCE
public static DatabaseReference getPostLikedRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.POSTS_LIKED_KEY);
}
public static DatabaseReference getPostLikedRef(String postId) {
    return getPostLikedRef().child(getCurrentUser().getEmail()
            .replace(".", ","))
            .child(postId);
}








// USER ID
public static String getUid() {
    String path = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().toString();
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}








// POST IMAGE REFERENCE
public static StorageReference getImagesSRef() {
    return FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(Constants.POST_IMAGES);
}








// COMMENT REFERENCE
public static DatabaseReference getCommentRef(String postId) {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.COMMENTS_KEY)
            .child(postId);
}







// RECORD

public static DatabaseReference getMyRecordRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_RECORD)
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}



public static void addToMyRecord(String node,final String id) {
    FirebaseUtils.getMyRecordRef().child(node).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            ArrayList<String> myPostCollection;
            if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                myPostCollection = new ArrayList<>(1);
                myPostCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myPostCollection);
            } else {
                myPostCollection = (ArrayList<String>) mutableData.getValue();
                myPostCollection.add(id);
                mutableData.setValue(myPostCollection);
            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

and the class on im send the post:

```
 public class PostCreateDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 1;
private View mRootView;
private Post mPost;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private Uri mSelectedImageUri;
private ImageView mPostDisplay;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    mPost = new Post();

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    mRootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_create_dialog, null);
    mPostDisplay = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_display);
    mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview).setOnClickListener(this);
    mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview).setOnClickListener(this);
    builder.setView(mRootView);
    return builder.create();


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.post_dialog_send_imageview:
            sendPost();
            break;
        case R.id.post_dialog_select_imageview:
            selectImage();
            break;
    }
}


private void selectImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
}

private void sendPost(){
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Sending post...");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.show();

    FirebaseUtils.getUserRef(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","))
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    final String postUid = FirebaseUtils.getUid();
                    TextView postDialogTextView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_edittext);
                    String text = postDialogTextView.getText().toString();

                    mPost.setUser(user);
                    mPost.setNumComments(0);
                    mPost.setNumLikes(0);
                    mPost.setTimeCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    mPost.setPostId(postUid);
                    mPost.setPostText(text);

                    if (mSelectedImageUri != null) {
                        FirebaseUtils.getImagesSRef()
                                .child(mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment())
                                .putFile(mSelectedImageUri)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(),
                                        new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                String url = Constants.POST_IMAGES + "/" + mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment();
                                                //String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                                mPost.setPostImageUrl(url);
                                                addToMyPostList(postUid);
                                            }


                                        });
                    } else {
                        addToMyPostList(postUid);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}

private void addToMyPostList(final String postUid){
    FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postUid)
            .setValue(mPost);
    FirebaseUtils.getMyPostRef().child(postUid).setValue(true)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    dismiss();
                }
            });

    FirebaseUtils.addToMyRecord(Constants.POSTS_KEY, postUid);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mSelectedImageUri = data.getData();
            mPostDisplay.setImageURI(mSelectedImageUri);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What line is 102 in `PostFragment`?

Comment: is this:  StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                        .getReference(mmPost.getPostImageUrl());
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(storageReference)
                        .into(viewHolder.postDisplayImageView);   @BlackHatSamurai

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai i try this but i have a new exception: }
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: location should not be a full URL.

Comment: Soundsdns like that is the problem, you just need to get the correct URL in there.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai What is the url? Where I find him sorry I'm new at this

Comment: You need to log into your firebase console and there will be a url that looks like `yourapp.firebaseio.com` and then from there you can add a path to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is here:

```
  //You only initialize. Never assign a value to PostImageUrl()
  mmPost = new Post();
            viewHolder.setNumComments(String.valueOf(model.getNumComments()));
            viewHolder.setNumLikes(String.valueOf(model.getNumLikes()));
            viewHolder.setTime(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(model.getTimeCreated()));
            viewHolder.setUsername(mmUser.getUser());
            viewHolder.setPostText(model.getPostText());







            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                     //This reference location is empty. mmPost is only initialized, and doesn't have PostURL assigned to it yet.
                    .getReference(mmPost.getPostImageUrl());
            Glide.with(getActivity())
```

You need to get the reference to the post URL by assigning a value after you create your post object:

```
mmPost = new Post();
mmPost.setPostURL(FirebaseUtils.getMyPostReference());
```

Or something like that.